# Executing a regular task on Scilab

Tags: automation, scilab

I'm currently working on the automation of a test bench (Subject of my work placement). It consists electronic loads (BK8610, BK8500), DC power supplies (BK9202, ETS60X14C) and multimeters (MetraEnergy).

I created a library of functions in Scilab to control all the devices at the same time (I can set paramaters and get measures using ethernet, serial ports and VISA interface). Now that every commands works fine, i'm trying to write a general script to do regular measures.

I thought of using tic() at the beginning of my script, then exec_time=toc() at the end an wait for 5s-exec_time before executing it again.

```
tic()
//My code
exec_time=toc()
//wait until the time is equal to 5s
//Repeat
```

Even if this could work, **I wonder if Scilab has a function which would be equivalent to an asynchronous interruption timer (commonly used on ATmega, stm32 and so on) ?** This would be much easier.

Hope this is clear. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `realtime` & `realtimeinit` is a solution for you. Modified example from Scilab help:

```
clc;
clear;

realtimeinit(1/2);//sets time unit to half a second
realtime(0);//sets current date to 0
for k=1:10
  realtime(k);
  mprintf('\r\ncurrent time is %.1f sec',k/2);
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to write a script wih this one.
I've already done a bunch of tests with my solution, it works well but it's not really "beatiful".

Comment: If this solution solves your problem, you may consider to accept it, thus others may also see that the question is not open any more. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and I observe a little time shift after 150~ cycles (a few seconds), so i kept my old algorithm. I'll accept it anyway because it is what I needed but it is just not as precise as an external quartz (Maybe because the PC I use has just one core ?).